# PTVS doesn't inspect class members

Tags: python, ironpython, ptvs

I'm using PTVS 2.2.2, IronPython 2.7, and VS 2015.  I'm encountering a weird problem that I'm assuming is user error.  I cannot mouse over a class field (e.g. `self.x`) and see its value.  I can mouse over `self` or a local variable without issue.

When the popup appears after hovering over `self`, I'm prompted with traversing down either `__class__` or `Raw View`.  I'm able to find the field name under `self -> Raw View -> Dynamic View` but it doesn't have the value, just the type.

Any ideas as to how to inspect a fields value easily?  It seems to me that this should be "easy" but I can't find anyone talking about it on the web.

Comment: It sounds like you're using the Managed debugger here. Try using Python debugger instead (if this is a PTVS project, you can change launcher to Standard in project properties).

Comment: I'm using some .NET Interop stuff, so I can't use the standard Python launcher.  I guess this is a limitation with PTVS and Managed code.

Comment: You can also try mixed-mode debugging. While it's mostly designed around C++, it actually also supports managed code, if you use debug attach rather than just starting your project (select Native, Managed and Python in Code Types). https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/wiki/Mixed-Mode-Debugging

Comment: That sort of makes sense, but what exactly am I attaching to?  I just have one solution with one project, and inside that IronPython code.

Comment: You would need to launch your project first _without debugging_ (Ctrl+F5), and then attach to the process that this results in (it might require putting some kind of message box or similar thing to pause execution until you can attach, if it's not an interactive app).